# Pimcore concern i18n

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5, pimcore-datahub

What statements concerning i18n are correct?

1. One document can have multiple languages.
2. One document always has exactly one language.
3. Labels in templates can be translated with shared translations.
4. Multiple language websites can be built via multiple document trees.
5. URLs can be translated with shared translations.

Try to get answers of this above question

Answer (score 0):

The correct answers are:
Multiple language websites can be built via multiple document trees.
One document always has exactly one language.
Labels in templates can be translated with shared translations.